# Most efficient way to retrieve an unoccupied point in a binary matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, random, matrix

Say we have a binary matrix (0 or 1, whatever), where 0 means unoccupied and 1 means occupied. The matrix is filled randomly with such values.

I know all the points that are occupied, but not those that aren't... that is, I can get an array of the points that are occupied, but not of those that aren't.

What is the most efficient way of getting a random, non-occupied point from the matrix?

I have tried getting getting a random point in the matrix like this:

```
x = random number from 0 to maxX
y = random number from 0 to maxY

while (x, y) is occupied:
    x = random number from 0 to maxX
    y = random number from 0 to maxY

return (x, y)
```

This has the best-case running time of nothing and worst-case of forever.

Another thing I've tried is

```
point[] unoccupied

for each y in matrix
    for each x int matrix
        if (x, y) is unoccupied
            push (x, y) to unoccupied

shuffle unoccupied

return unoccupied[0]
```

This has a time complexity of at least O(x * y). Most of the time it's slower than the first approach, but it's a lot more stable.

The task is trivial enough, but are there more efficient ways to accomplish this?

---

This isn't any kind of homework or the sort. I'm implementing a snake-like game and am trying to place a new apple/cookie to some unoccupied place.

Comment: How do you get the list of occupied cells and why can't a similar process get you a list of unoccupied cells?

Comment: @DonRoby I have in knowledge the snake and the pieces it consists of. Each piece holds info of its position in the board. I'm not going to hold information of pieces that don't exist.

Comment: Yes I would also recommend you create a separate list of unoccupied points and use e.g. observer pattern to notify this list every time a square gets occupied, then it's a simple matter of generating random index to get a point from unoccupied list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). This way you can keep track of your occupied cells and at the same time, you can easily find unoccupied regions. Most of the operations on the quadtree are O(log n) in the size of the matrix.

Comment: this looks promising. however, I could not find any mention of using areas other than `n^2 x n^2`. how about odd-n sizes? the board may also have different width and height

Comment: There is no issue using any value of n. You just have to make a decision about in which side goes the middle index and stick to it (for both dimensions). Making n=2^k just save you from some extra validations, but the algorithms are basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use random, and if it is occupied increment the x and y iteratively until you reach an unoccupied cell.

Comment: What if I get an occupied cell whose all cells to the *right* and *down* are also occupied?

Comment: When you reach the end, start in 0,0 until you reach the first random x,y.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good solution. Apples would more often than not appear next to an occupied point. It eats the randomness a bit.

Comment: You are right. Use true randomness if you have less than half the array occupied, use my solution if you have more than half occupied (in this case true randomness may last a lot of time and anyway an apple will be next to an occupied cell).